# Magento 2 - documentation library for modules

Tags: magento2, documentation

I am big fan of Java developer docs - http://devdocs.io/haxe~java/lang/abstractstringbuilder#codePointBefore ., I dont find similar one for magento 2. Can anyone share the link if you have a know how?

Answer (score 0):

Please check given below URLs for detail guide about magento1 and magento2.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ext-best-practices/bk-ext-best-practices.html

https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/

Comment: I wanted the stuffs that explains each module in magento and its functionalities. The php function name and description about it. I went through the documentation completely., B ut I cannot find anything like this though

Comment: for example Catalog module - What it does., The name of methods defined in blocks and models., What does it do.. and so on